# Manipulate regex variable after a pattern match

Tags: regex

Search Regex expression is:

```
_(01|02|03|04)_
```

Replace expression is:

```
_$1_
```

Result is:

```
_01_/_02_/_03_/_04_ (depending on the match)
```

How do I manipulate the variable so it strips away the 0 to return a single digit:

```
_1_/_2_/_3_/_4_
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make the match be: `0(1|2|3|4)` and the replacement be `$1`.